# Set permissions on accessing a certain file on S3 using IAM with the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to set the users who can access certain files stored on Amazon's S3 with IAM and also using the PHP SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to generate a policy with the instructions you want. The [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) makes this a lot easier.

From there, you can use the [`AmazonS3::set_bucket_policy()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/set_bucket_policy) method to apply the policy you created.